# Post Table is not Updating in Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, updating

After creating my posts, I tried to submit a post, but I discovered that the post was not updating into the database, below is index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <div class="flex justify-center">
        <div class="w-8/12 bg-white p-6 rounded-lg">
            <form action="{{ route('posts') }}" method="post" class="mb-4">
                @csrf
                <div class="mb-4">
                    <label for="body" class="sr-only">Body</label>
                    <textarea name="body" id="body" cols="30" rows="4" class="by-gray-100 border-2
                    w-full p-4 rounded lg @error('body') border-red-500 @enderror" placeholder="Post something!"></textarea>
                    @error('body')
                        <div class="text-red-500 mt-3 text-sm">
                            {{$message}}
                        </div>    
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit" class="bg-blue-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded
                    font-medium">Post</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            @if ($posts->count()))
                iterate

            @else
                There are no posts...
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

PostController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        $posts= Post::get(); //Collect all...
        
        return view('posts.index', [
            'posts' => $posts
        ]);
    }

    public function store(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
            'body' => 'required',
        ]);

       /* Post::create([
            'user_id' => auth()->id(),
            'body' => $request->body,
        ]);*/
    }
}
```

Post.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable= [
        'body'
    ];
}
```

my web.php file

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LogoutController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController;
use App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController;
use App\Http\Controllers\PostController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    //return view('welcome');
});

// Route::get('/', function () {
//     return view('posts.index');
// });

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
})->name('home');

Route::get('/dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'index'] )
->name('dashboard')
->middleware('auth');

Route::get('/register', [RegisterController::class, 'index'] )->name('register');
Route::post('/register', [RegisterController::class, 'store'] );

Route::get('/login', [LoginController::class, 'index'] )->name('login');
Route::post('/login', [LoginController::class, 'store'] );

Route::post('/logout', [LogoutController::class, 'store'] )->name('logout');

Route::get('/login', [LoginController::class, 'index'] )->name('login');

Route::get('/posts', [PostController::class, 'index'] )->name('posts');
Route::post('/posts', [PostController::class, 'store'] );
```

Have checked through to see if there are any errors, but have found none, though am new to Laravel, and am using Laravel 8.1, but yet still the post is not updating into the database

Have updated my question, I tried the form action, but it didn't work, it tells me posts.store not defined, though I already made the posts.store in my web.php file, you can check

Comment: Assuming you are aware that the code which would create a post is commented out - you're trying to save `user_id`, but it is not in your `$fillable` array.

Comment: In the `store()` method, there is no code to update any post. To update a post you need to send it's `id` in the form or in the url. `user_id` is not in the fillable

Answer (score 0):

How are your routes defined? You likely need to update your form action to posts.store

```
<form action="{{ route('posts.store') }}" method="post" class="mb-4">
```

instead of

```
<form action="{{ route('posts') }}" method="post" class="mb-4">
```

Comment: Tried it, It didn't work. But I have a web.php file where the routs are clearly defined, I will post it now

Comment: It looks like you aren't assigning a name to your store route. Does it have a name if you view it using artisan route:list? I would suggest 
Route::post('/posts', [PostController::class, 'store'] )->name('posts'store');

Comment: Just coming back online after a while, so am sorry for the late response...

I already have a Routes, I would paste it here so you can see how they are defined...



Route::get('/posts', [PostController::class, 'index'] )->name('posts');
Route::post('/posts', [PostController::class, 'store'] );

Comment: Also, I tried the die dump in my PostController, and it actually gave me back my values, but whenever, I tried to post normally using this 

 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        dd('ok');
        $this->validate($request, [
             'body' => 'required',
         ]);
    }

the above, it only gives me a blank page...